# How to Conclude a Git Cherry-Pick?

Tags: git, version-control, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

Yesterday I cherry-picked two commits into my main branch, one of them caused merge conflicts and I resolved them, committed and pushed them to origin. Today I am attempting to pull from the server when I get the following error:

```
$ git pull
fatal: You have not concluded your cherry-pick (CHERRY_PICK_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you can merge.
$
```

Git status reads:

```
$ git status
# On branch main
# Your branch is behind 'origin/main' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
$
```

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
$ git cherry-pick --continue
usage: git cherry-pick [options] <commit-ish>
$
```

Any idea on how I could resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What git version are you using? `git cherry-pick --continue`has been introduced in August 2011 (https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a5d80f4ca16fdb1f2577474ad94135839853a3e, git1.7.7+)

Comment: @VonC, you should submit this as an answer. It is now the correct one.

Comment: @cjbarth I have posted it as an answer below.

Comment: I've asked this question in Spanish [here](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2733/75) without having read this one before.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solved with the following: `rm .git/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` I realize this is dangerous as this doesn't guarantee internal consistency within git, but no issues for me so far...

Comment: Why the down vote? It worked for me just fine and hasn't caused any problems.

Comment: Sure, this will work for *most* people, however it's an example of some worst-practices and could be catastrophic for *some* people.

Comment: For my case, I use SourceTree and did cherry pick by mistake. It didn't commit anything and a class conflicted with merge. I discarded it. Then I wanted to pull some commits. The pull failed. I tried your code but it didn't work. That's because you got some downvotes.

Comment: this works too https://stackoverflow.com/a/12407866/302925 and is way safer

Answer (score 180):

Next time try `git cherry-pick --abort`, otherwise what you did should more or less work.

Answer (score 16):

Since my [previous answer from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25138563/6309), the proper command nowadays (2018) is `git cherry-pick --quit`.
And before Git 2.19 (Q3 2018), "`git cherry-pick --quit`" failed to remove `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` even though we won't be in a cherry-pick session after it returns, which has been corrected.

See [commit 3e7dd99](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e7dd9920823fc2a88f8ec5390bd100d707f9129) (16 Aug 2018) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 39e415c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/39e415cfd1390ed31a61ca0ca175530302c9a58c), 20 Aug 2018)</sup>

> ### cherry-pick: fix --quit not deleting CHERRY_PICK_HEAD
>
> `--quit` is supposed to be `--abort` but without restoring `HEAD`.
>   Leaving `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` behind could make other commands mistake that `cherry-pick` is still ongoing (e.g. "`git commit --amend`" will refuse to work). **Clean it too**.
>
> For `--abort`, this job of deleting `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` is on "`git reset`" so we don't need to do anything else. But let's add extra checks in `--abort` tests to confirm.

Comment: Even though `git cherry-pick --continue` does not work, git cli still recommends that to me. `git cherry-pick --quit` works just fine.

Comment: @AmoghJahagirdar What version of Git are you using?

Comment: `git version 2.21.0.windows.1`

Comment: @AmoghJahagirdar Can you check if the issue persists with Git For Windows 2.27? (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Answer (score 8):

If the `git cherry-pick --continue` doesn't work, that means git is too old: that option was introduced for git 1.7.8 (Dec. 2011) in [commit 5a5d80f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a5d80f4ca16fdb1f2577474ad94135839853a3e)

> It works by dropping the first instruction from .git/sequencer/todo and performing the remaining cherry-picks listed there, with options (think "`-s`" and "`-X`") from the initial command listed in "`.git/sequencer/opts`".

These days (2014), that would be the command to use when you see "`You have not concluded your cherry-pick`".

Answer (score 1):

Another option: with Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), a `git cherry-pick --continue` will actually work!

When one step in multi step cherry-pick or revert is reset or committed, the command line prompt script failed to notice the current status, which has been improved.

See [commit e981bf7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e981bf75251ecab712fa70ea2fe995a973ed5dba) (01 Jul 2019) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8a4acc5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a4acc5f4cdd811476ffa0b5c63ae4cc35ef288f), 19 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `git-prompt`: improve `cherry-pick`/`revert` detection
>
> If the user commits or resets a conflict resolution in the middle of a sequence of cherry-picks or reverts then `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`/`REVERT_HEAD` will be removed and so in the absence of those files we need to check **`.git/sequencer/todo`** to see if there is a cherry-pick or revert in progress.
>
> See if a `cherry-pick` or `revert` is in progress, if the user has committed a conflict resolution with '`git commit`' in the middle of a sequence of picks or reverts then `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`/`REVERT_HEAD` will not exist so we have to read the `todo` file.