# How to merge two commit, without using rebase in git

Tags: git, merge

I'm using git for push my task to project, my problem is I have too many commit, so I want to merge two commit in one:
example: here my git log:

```
5928bd5 myname-task7xx
599c7bf myname-task7xx
```

I want to merge 5928bd5 into 599c7bf . Usually, I use git rebase(pick,squash) to merge them, but my partner said that way too long, and he tell me should try cherry-pick. So I try:

```
git check out master
git cherry-pick 599c7bf
git merge 5928bd5
```

and i have this error:

```
fatal: You have not concluded your cherry-pick (CHERRY_PICK_HEAD exists)
```

So please help me to fix it, or tell me a shorter way to merge them

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Conclude a Git Cherry-Pick?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397752/how-to-conclude-a-git-cherry-pick)

Comment: The problem is solved but i still don't know how to merge them, the git say Already-up-to-date, but when i check git show, i see nothing change :(

Comment: cherry picking into a branch & merging commits are not the same. No amount of cherry-picking is going to squash multiple commits for you.

Comment: So, can I merge commit with git commit --amend ??

Comment: *merge* means something very specific in git, if you mean that you want to add changes to the last commit, then yes `git commit --amend` will do the job.

Comment: Yeah! I can add changes with git commit --amend, thanks you!