# What difference does `.git/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` make when committing?

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

**NB:** This is a rewording of an earlier post of mine (now deleted).  The rewording intends to give the post a different focus.

---

Upon running `git cherry-pick`, `git` reported that there was a conflict.  I resolved the conflict, and then ran `git cherry-pick --continue`.  At this point, `$GIT_EDITOR` popped up a `COMMIT_EDITMSG` buffer pre-populated with the cherry-picked commit's original message along with some additional info, which included the warning:

```
# It looks like you may be committing a cherry-pick.
# If this is not correct, please remove the file
#   .git/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD
# and try again.
```

I checked to see what happened if I "deleted" (actually, just temporarily renamed) the `.git/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` file.  The immediate outward effect this had was to remove the `|CHERRY-PICKING` indication from my `git`-aware prompt.

Other than this change in my prompt, and possibly some differences in the pre-populated information in the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` buffer, what difference would it make to perform the commit with or without the `.git/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` file in place?

---

To be more precise, I'm trying to compare two scenarios here.

In the first scenario, I run

```
% git cherry-pick --continue
```

...and (disregarding the warning quoted earlier) I proceed with the commit as usual.

In the second scenario, I run

```
% rm .git/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD
% git commit
```

...and proceed with the commit as usual.

(Assume that I use the same commit message in both scenarios.)

How would the *end results* of these two scenarios differ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer depends on what you were doing.  Using `--continue` finishes the sequence—but if the sequence was just the one cherry-pick, there wasn't really a sequence anyway.

Either way, however, *removing* the `.git/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` definitely has one additional significant effect: *finishing* a conflicted cherry-pick re-uses the original commit's author-name-email-and-date information.  You are always the committer of any new commit, but all commits have not just one person-and-timestamp: each new commit has two entries, one for "committer" (you, making the commit, just now) and one for "author" (whoever wrote the original commit, and whenever they did that).  Cherry-pick preserves the authorship information from the original commit.

#### The sequencer

Both `git cherry-pick` and `git revert`—which are actually the same command internally; revert just "works backwards"—use what Git calls the *sequencer*.  That is, you can pick multiple commits all at once:

```
git cherry-pick notthis..that thistoo
```

to cherry pick all commits "after" `notthis`, up through and including `that`, and also the one specific commit `thistoo`.  You might, for instance, decide to cherry-pick every commit on `feature/X` that grows from `develop`, plus one bug fix commit `fix-1234`, for testing purposes:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b testbranch
git cherry-pick develop..feature/X fix-1234
```

Anyway, the point here is that this might cherry-pick a dozen or more commits, and somewhere along the way there could be a merge conflict, that requires that `git cherry-pick` stop and get assistance.

Aside: the model here—the Unix/Linux command line—is that you enter a command into a command-interpreter called a *shell*.  The shell passes control of the human-interface to the new command, which retains it until the command finishes and exits.  Once the command exits, there is no trace left of the command itself: anything *permanent* must be saved in files.

So: If cherry-pick must stop, how will it know where to resume?  The answer is by saving information in files.  If you're cherry-picking a single commit, Git saves just the `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` file, which records the ID of the commit being cherry-picked.  If you're cherry-picking *multiple* commits, though, Git saves the conflicted commit as for a single commit, *and* saves the remaining information in a sequencing directory (whose location has moved some over time).

Running `git cherry-pick --continue` directs the (new, separate instance of) cherry pick command to pick up where the previous one left off.  Git will first run a `git commit` for you, then locate the sequencing information and finish as much of the sequence as it can, stopping again at the next conflict, or finishing all the cherry-picks.

Running `git commit` instead, Git will notice the `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` file and use that as you have seen.  When the commit finishes, that command exits and does nothing with the sequencer.  If there *is* sequencer data left behind, you can now `git cherry-pick --continue`: Git will notice that the commit is already done and simply continue / finish the sequencer operation.

Note that you can, instead of finishing the operation, use `git cherry-pick --abort`.  This terminates the operation and puts things back to the way they were before you started.  As of Git 2.19, you can instead use `git cherry-pick --quit` to stop (a la `--abort`) but *not* put things back to how they were before you started.  That is, it stops any future cherry-picking operations, without undoing the ones you have done so far.  (This operation was missing before 2.19.)

The `git status` command now notices if there is a sequence in progress, and reports that you are in the middle of whatever it is you were doing.  (This is a big improvement from the Git 1.7 era, when it didn't.)

Comment: Wow, that's a great one!  Thank you.

Comment: You now have `git cherry-pick --quit`, but it fully works only with Git 2.19 (Q3 2018): see "[How to Conclude a Git Cherry-Pick?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51957030/6309)".

Comment: Also, the presence of .git/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD makes another difference, even when cherry-picking a single commit.  When git cherry-picking, git preserves the author date (and probably the author name/email) of the original commit.

Comment: @Alex35: True - I'll rephrase the above slightly. (I have the details in the longer section but it bears mentioning at the top.)

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, `git cherry-pick --quit` also deletes `.git/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`, but, in addition, the message "If this is not correct, please remove the file `.git/CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`" will change with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020): Accesses to two pseudorefs have been updated to properly use ref API.

See [commit b8825ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b8825ef233840136bd01a9619b36af515f498eb2), [commit b6d2558](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6d2558c9ea37382078635022f8932565bea8ca1), [commit c8e4159](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8e4159efd226218d827b5da71fc8f95f8172412), [commit 3f9f1ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f9f1acccf32fb1feda0f7ea8533bed2b594b1a0) (21 Aug 2020) by [Han-Wen Nienhuys (`hanwen`)](https://github.com/hanwen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e699684](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e699684cf6bdfd4d6fd9086a6935168f86a0177e), 31 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/commit`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6d2558c9ea37382078635022f8932565bea8ca1): suggest update-ref for pseudoref removal
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Han-Wen Nienhuys</sup>

> When pseudorefs move to a **different ref storage mechanism**, pseudorefs **no longer can be removed with '`rm`'**.
> Instead, suggest a "`update-ref -d`" command, which will work regardless of ref storage backend.

The new message will suggest: `git update-ref -d CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`